# Mockito - underlying service is null

Tags: java, mockito

I have a Service A which autowired Service  B and is using a method from Service B. 
Service B autowired another Service C and is using a method from it.

I am writing a test for Service A and the test fails at the call where Service B is invoked.At this point Service C is null.

I have tried  @Mock for Service B. Nothing seems to work. How can i successfully test this service which is failing on a service that it isnt explicitly autowiring.

```
//Service A

@Service
public class FileServiceImpl{
  @Autowired
  private FileNameServiceImpl fileNameService;

  public void createFile(String fileName){
  String targetFileName = fileNameService.getTargetFileName(fileName);
  }
}
//Service B
@Service
public class FileNameServiceImpl{
  @Autowired
  private CustomDateService customDateService

  public String getTargetFileName(String fileName){
    return fileName + customDateService.getCustomDate();
    }
}
//CustomDate - this is an interace. The Impl is in another package.
public interfaceCustomDateService{
 public String getCustomDate();
  }
```

I am trying to test FileServiceImpl , however it fails with a NullPointer Exception because customDateService is null.
Even though, FileServiceImpl is not calling customDateService.

This is what I have for test thus far:

```
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FileServiceImplTest {
  @Spy
  @InjectMocks
  private FileServiceImpl fileServiceImpl;

   @Mock
  private FileNameServiceImpl fileNameService;

 @Before
 public void init() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
public void testFileName() {
    String fileName = "test1.txt"; 

    fileServiceImpl.createFile(fileName);  // Test Fails here 
    Mockito.validateMockitoUsage();



}
```

Comment: Are these integration test? and could you post some code please?

Answer (score 2):

As Shane eluded, this sounds like you're maybe integration testing.
If so, make sure the context of your test encompasses the autowired components.

You should post some code, as it's hard to know what exactly is going on here.

If you aren't integration testing, don't rely on autowiring, just construct new ServiceA manually passing in a mocked ServiceB.

Also make sure to initialise your mocks.

```
private ServiceA serviceA;

@Mock
private ServiceB serviceB;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks();

    serviceA = new ServiceA(serviceB);
}
```

EDIT:
First of all, as good practice you should favor constructor injection over field injection in Spring.
So set up the service classes with Autowired constructors.

Also, I'm pretty sure with a mockito Spy you have to initialise the class.

If you switch to use constructor Autowiring you can inject the mocks manually.

```
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FileServiceImplTest {
  @Spy
  private FileServiceImpl fileServiceImpl;

  @Mock
  private FileNameServiceImpl fileNameService;

  @Before
  public void init() throws Exception {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

      fileServiceImpl = new FileServiceImpl(fileNameService);
  }

  @Test
  public void testFileName() {
      String fileName = "test1.txt"; 

      fileServiceImpl.createFile(fileName);  <-- now this shouldn't fail
      Mockito.validateMockitoUsage();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will update the question with the code.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. However FileServiceImpl does not have a constructor of that type . I dont have permissions to edit /update it.

Comment: Even so, try creating an instance ServiceA  -> FileServiceImpl servcieA = new FileServiceImpl();